# How to get the month out of a MySQL timestamp using JS

Tags: javascript

I have JSON outputting this timestamp 2011-05-03 12:00:00. How would i use Javascript to just grab the month out of it?

Comment: are you trying to get the `string` or the actual `Date` `object`?

Comment: just the String value that says "05"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have string "2011-05-03 12:00:00" then simply use

`var month = "2011-05-03 12:00:00".split("-")[1];`

or if you want to be able to extract all of the parts easily, use

`var month = new Date("2011-05-03 12:00:00').getMonth();`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number, just use `.getMonth()`. It will return a number between 0 and 11, so you might want to add 1 *(**EDIT**: this works in Chrome, BUT Firefox and IE9 does not seem to recognize the date format)*.

```
var month=new Date('2011-05-03 12:00:00').getMonth() + 1;
```

or if you just want the string representation with the leading zero:

```
var month=('2011-05-03 12:00:00').split('-')[1];
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BwZ2E/)
- [Javascript .split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: the first code example this doesn't work in my firebug.  It looked like it would...

Comment: Yes, I just tested it in some browsers, updated my answer based on that. Some of them do not seem to recognize this specific date format.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment on your post above.  If just the `string` you can do a simple split:
`var d = "2011-05-03 12:00:00"; var m = d.split('-')[1]`

otherwise this seems to work:

`new Date("2011-05-03 12:00:00").getMonth()+1`

Comment: The second one without time does not seem to work either cross-browser (tested in FF4).

Answer (score 0):

How about looking at it in a different way:

What if your SQL's select statement also selects `MONTH(timestamp)` and then store it in the JSON response as an additional field in the JSON object. Since it seems that getitng the month isn't universal between all browsers, this might be the most generic/easiest way to do it, less parsing, less error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `split` the string. You're throwing most of the result away, so that's very wasteful.

`Date` objects likewise (but worse).

Use this for great victory:

```
alert('2011-05-03 12:00:00'.substr(5,2));
// Result: '05'
```